# Having an issue publishing from Sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore

I'm getting this error when trying to publish any item from Sitecore to the web. Was working fine the other day, not sure what I did to crash this.

> Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Root item is not defined    at
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(Object value, String message)
>   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.Initialize(Index index)
>   at Sitecore.Search.Index.AddCrawler(ICrawler crawler)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[]
>   properties)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred,
>   IFactoryHelper helper)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred,
>   IFactoryHelper helper)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingManager.UpdateIndexAsync(Database
>   database)    at Sitecore.MainUtil.RaiseEvent[T](EventHandler`1
>   subscribers, Object sender, T eventArgs)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.HistoryEngine.RegisterItemSaved(Item item,
>   ItemChanges changes)    at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender,
>   TEventArgs e)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1
>   handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean
>   updateStatistics, Boolean silent)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext.Dispose()    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.CopyToTarget(Item sourceVersion)
>   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.PublishVersionToTarget(Item
>   sourceVersion, Item targetItem, Boolean targetCreated)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.ExecuteAction(PublishItemContext
>   context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.Process(PublishItemContext
>   context)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext
>   context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
>   entries, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
>   entries, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
>   entries, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1
>   entries, PublishContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext
>   context)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext
>   context)    at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[]
>   parameters)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the index configuration is corrupted.

Go to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page and find:

```
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
```

Check every location under that node - they all should have `<Root>` tag with the proper location root specified.

Comment: So the issue is that some items that I created a package for are not matching up to what I had since I overrided the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Sitecore logs. As per my finding it is occurred because  I've specified wrong username/password in connectionstrings.config. Please make sure username and password is correct.